# Javascript get reference to a just created object without using id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if there is a way to do something like:

```
<label>TestLabel</label>
<script type="text/javascript">

    ... Get reference here for the just created object, like below...

    alert($(this).text());

</script>
```

As I have several objects with dynamic behaviour on my pages, that would avoid me to use id´s. It would be easier for me to attach direct changes to these objects in a script (loaded through ajax for each object) keeping each DOM logic just together the object.

The above code doesn´t work (show undefined), but is there a closest way to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Assign the object to a variable, e.g. `var newobj = $('<div>');`, then you can use `newobj.text()`.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no DIV´s here. I tried $('<label>') but it does not work...

Comment: That was just an example. Whatever it is, assign it to a variable.

Comment: You understand that `$('<label>')` creates a __new__ label element, it doesn't have anything to do with the `<label>TestLabel</label>` in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with something like:

```
<label>TestLabel</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
        sibling = scripts[scripts.length - 1].previousSibling;

    while (sibling.nodeType == 3) {
        sibling = sibling.previousSibling;
    }
</script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4XQAA/

But it indeed looks like a bad idea at the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You should cache references to objects:

```
var $this = $(this);
alert($this.text());
alert($this.html());
```

Comment: That's only needed if you're trying to save the reference in a closure or access it in a nested function that has a different context.

Comment: It's good to save references to jquery objects you'll be using often, in general, like `$('body')` or `$(document)`, but I think I mostly just answered the wrong question. What's this guy trying to do?

Comment: The wording is poor, but I think zerkms's answer reflects what he actually meant.